# GWT serializable Object

Tags: gwt, serialization

Details: I think I am returning an invalid List of objects from a rpc. **I think its the Type which cant get serialized.. does anyone know a way to Serialize it ? or some work around?**

I got a class that can't get serialized I am getting the following exception:
**cause:** `"com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'gwt.client.objects.NamedObject' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = gwt.client.objects.NamedObject@613bc2a6"`

This is the 'NamedObject' class source code where it is all about which I am returning a List off.

```
public class NamedObject<T> implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private T object;

    public void setNamedObject(String name, T object){
    setName(name);
    setObject(object);
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Object getObject() {
        return object;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your object parameter is of type T, which can be anything and in particular something that GWT does not know how to serialize.

You could try this

```
public class NamedObject<T extends IsSerializable> implements Serializable {
...
}
```

Although I'm not sure that will work. If not, you will probably have to create multiple classes for each type that T can be :

```
public class StringNamedObject implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String object;
}

public class DateNamedObject implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private Date object;
}

....
```

Comment: I will accept it when it is validated. So when it got its first +1